# How to get socket states from socket winsock2

Tags: visual-c++, winsock2

Hi I'm new to C++ winsock2 sockets and I've been stuck at this for a while.

How do I get if a socket is connected, bound, listening or closed from the socket/file descriptor passed as an argument.

Note : I want to figure out the socket state without attempting to bind/connect/listen/closesocket because that will return a result and perform the operation. Example : if I wanted to check whether a socket is connected to a server I should attempt to connect and get the result which I don't want.

I am trying to achieve something like this.

```
// Using Winsock2 API.
bool isSocketBound(SOCKET s) {
    // Check if socket is bound without attempting to bind.
    // The code which I'm not able to figure out.
    return isBound;
}

// Same goes for the other functions.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get if a socket is connected, bound, listening or closed from the socket/file descriptor passed as an argument.

There is no single socket API to query a `SOCKET`'s current state.  However:

- [`getsockname()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockname) will tell you whether the socket is bound locally or not.
- [`getpeername()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getpeername) will tell you whether the socket is connected to a remote peer or not.
- [`getsockopt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockopt) with the [`SOL_SOCKET:SO_ACCEPTCONN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sol-socket-socket-options) option will tell you whether a connection-oriented (ie, TCP) `SOCKET` is `listen()`'ing or not.

  Alternatively, if you try to `connect()` on a `listen()`'ing socket, you will get a `WSAEINVAL` error.  If you try to `listen()` on a `connect()`'ed socket, you will get a `WSAEISCONN` error.

  Alternatively, if the socket is at least bound locally, then you can use `getsockname()` to get its local IP/port and then use [`GetTcpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable), [`GetTcpTable2()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable2), or [`GetExtendedTcpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getextendedtcptable) to find out whether that IP/port is in a `LISTENING` state or not.
- If a `SOCKET` has been closed locally, the `SOCKET` is not valid to begin with, so you can't query it for anything.  The best thing you can do is just set the `SOCKET` to `INVALID_SOCKET` when you are done using it, and then check for that condition when needed.  On the other hand, if the socket has been closed remotely but not locally yet, then the `SOCKET` is still valid, but there is no way to query its close state.  The only way to know if the socket has been closed by the peer is if a `recv()` operation reports 0 bytes received, or if a `send()` operation fails with a connection error, or if you are using the `SOCKET` in asynchronous mode (`WSAAsyncSelect()` or `WSAEventSelect()`) and receive an `FD_CLOSE` notification for it.

> Note : I want to figure out the socket state without attempting to bind/connect/listen/closesocket because that will return a result and perform the operation. Example : if I wanted to check whether a socket is connected to a server I should attempt to connect and get the result which I don't want.

Why are you not simply keeping track of the state in your own code?  If you `bind()` a `SOCKET` and it succeeds, then you know it is bound locally.  If you `connect()` and it succeeds, then you know it is bound locally and is connected to a remote server.  You should maintain a `state` variable along-side your `SOCKET` variable, and keep the `state` updated with each state-changing operation you perform on the `SOCKET`.

Comment: The reason I'm not keeping track of the socket state in my code is that the constructor of my class takes in a socket, and I wanted to figure out whether the socket passed in the constructor is bound or not.

Comment: @GGBOI250 why not just have the caller pass in a parameter telling you the state? Don't guess.

Comment: Leabeau I can do that, but a caller might unintentionally make a mistake while passing in the state.

Comment: Quote: "*getsockname() will tell you whether the socket is bound locally or not.*" That's not clear. getsockname() from an unbound socket returns `WSAEINVAL (10022)` that means "The socket has not been bound to an address with bind, or ADDR_ANY is specified in bind but connection has not yet occurred." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockname#return-value

Comment: @Ingo "*getsockname() from an unbound socket returns WSAEINVAL*" - And, your point is...? That doesn't negate what I said in my answer. You can call `getsockname()` and based on what it reports you will know whether the socket is bound locally (returns 0) or not (returns `SOCKET_ERROR` - use `WSAGetLastError()` to find out *why*, if you want to know). Same with `getpeername()`.

Comment: My point is that you do not get a clear statement if the socket is bound. You get `WSAEINVAL (10022)` from `WSAGetLastError()` and not more. And 10022 says the socket has not been bound **OR** it is bound with `ADDR_ANY`. So what? Is it bound or not?